# Jest & Enzyme | Received value must be a function, received undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, async-await, jestjs, enzyme

I have a small function, that check if the name of a user is unique. See below:

```
export const validateUsername = value =>
  listUsers({ once: true }).then(({ data }) => {
    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.find(userData => userData.username === value)) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-throw-literal
      throw 'Username already exists';
    }
  });
```

I want to write some tests for it. But I get this error

```
Received value must be a function, but instead "undefined" was found
```

Can you explain to me what is wrong. I mean, this is an async function, and at the time it is undefined, but not sure what it wants me to do.

```
  it('Accept the data if the passed userName is unique', async () => {
    expect(await validateUsername('Username is unique')).not.toThrow();
  });
```

Comment: If you're using `toThrow` you have to pass a function to `expect`.

Comment: So, If I say `validateUsernamefn = jest.fn();`, and I say `beforeEach(() => {validateUsername = validateUsernameFn}`, will this work. I am importing validateusername from the index file.

Comment: Just so you know, I did this and it seems to be working: `  it('Accept the data if the passed userName is unique', async () => {
    expect(() => validateUsername('Username is unique')).not.toThrow();
  });` Is this correct fo you?

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant.

Comment: Actually that approach doesn't work since calling `validateUsername` **never** throws an `Error`, it returns a `Promise` that might reject with an `Error`, so that test will **always** pass, even if an `Error` gets thrown and the `Promise` rejects.  Instead, you need to test the returned `Promise`...see my answer below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`validateUsername` returns a `Promise` that can reject with an `Error`...

...so test that the returned `Promise` either [`.resolves`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#resolves) or [`.rejects`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#rejects) as expected:

```js
const listUsers = async() => Promise.resolve({data: [{ username: 'existing username' }]});

export const validateUsername = value =>
  listUsers({ once: true }).then(({ data }) => {
    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.find(userData => userData.username === value)) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-throw-literal
      throw new Error('Username already exists');  // <= throw an Error instead of just a string
    }
  });

it('Accept the data if the passed userName is unique', async () => {
  await expect(validateUsername('Username is unique')).resolves.not.toThrow();  // Success!
});

it('throws error if username already exists', async () => {
  await expect(validateUsername('existing username')).rejects.toThrow('Username already exists');  // Success!
});
```

(Note that you need to throw an `Error` instead of just a string to check its message with [`toThrow`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror))

Comment: Actually, that worked out really well, and it is cleaner on my side.